# Proof regarding the square root of a natural number $m>1$ and a prime number $p$, when $p \nmid m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I am self studying from "A logical introduction to proof" by Daniel W.Cunningham,one of those textbooks that unfortunately do not contain answers to end-of-chapter exercises.Could someone help me with the following problem?

*Let **p be a prime** number and **m>1 be a natural number**.Prove that **if $p\nmid m$ then $\sqrt{mp}$ is irrational**.*

**My attempt:**

Let p be a prime number and m $\in \Bbb{N} $ where m>1 (i.e.m>=2).The proof proceeds by regular mathematical induction.

**The base step** invovles proving that (p $\nmid 2$) $\Rightarrow$ ($\sqrt{2p} $ is irrational).By contraposition,we need to prove that ($\sqrt{2p} $ is rational) $\Rightarrow$ ($p\mid 2$).By defintion $\sqrt{2p}={a\over b} $ for some integers a and b where b$\neq 0 $ and gcd(a,b)=1.Therefore ${2p=}{a^2\over b^2} $ and hence ${2b^2 p=a^2} $ by squaring both sides and subsequent multplication.

Furthermore, ${p\mid a^2}$ and by implication ${p\mid a}$ which by definition suggests ${a=pk}$ for some k $\in \Bbb{Z}$. Consequently ${2b^2 p=p^2k^2 }$ then ${2b^2 = pk^2}$ hence ${p \mid 2b^2}$ which by Euclid's Lemma suggests **either** **(i) ${p \mid 2}$ or (ii) ${p \mid b^2}$** .

Now in the case where **(i) ${p\mid 2}$**,the conclusion to the base step has been verified.

Consider the case that **(ii) ${p\mid b^2}$**,then by the corrolary to Euclid's Lemma, ${p\mid b}$ as well.With ${p\mid b}$ and ${p\mid a}$,we have a prime number p that divides both a and b when by assumption gcd(a,b)=1.This implies that ${p\mid b}$ is false and hence that ${p\mid b^2}$ is false by contraposition,leaving us with **case(i)** as verified above.

Does this prove the base step?

Regarding the inductive step i do not know how to link the induction conclusion to the induction hypothesis...it is as if the conclusion can be arrived at without even considering the hypothesis in the inductive step,which to my understanding means the 'dominos have not been aligned' in the typical induction-dominos imagery.

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: As there is no clear route from $\sqrt{mp}\notin \Bbb Q$ to $\sqrt{(m+1)p}\notin \Bbb Q$ it seems that this approach is not ideal.

Comment: yikes...since the question appears in the induction chapters...i just thought this approach would be fine...Also,how can you tell that there is no clear route??? Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to try induction to prove this because induction will prove it for ALL $m$, but this is false if $p \mid m$.

Your proof works more directly for $m$:

Suppose $\sqrt{pm}=\frac{a}{b}$ for some coprime positive integers $a$ and $b$. Then $b^2 p m = a^2$. Then $p \mid a^2$. As $p$ is prime we have $p\mid a$, that is $a=p k$ for some integer $k$. Then $b^2 p m = p^2 k^2$, so $b^2 m = pk^2$. This means $p\mid b^2m$. Again, as $p$ is prime this implies $p\mid b$ or $p\mid m$, but the hypothesis tell us $p \not\mid m$, so we must have $p\mid b$. So we now have $p\mid a$ and $p\mid b$, a contradiction to the fact that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Thank you,i think the logic is very similar to my base step...I just instantly jumped to using induction to prove it...how does one tell whether induction is appropriate or not at the outset?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don’t need to recur, the proof is standard, and almost the same as the proof that $\sqrt2$ is irrationnal.

Let’s assume there is a $x = \frac{a}{b}$ so that $x^2 = mp$ and $pgcd(a,b) =1$

Then $\frac{a^2}{b^2} = mp$

$a^2 = mp b^2$

then

either p is a prime factor of b, which means it is not one of a (since $pgcd(a,b) = 1$) and therefore $a^2 = m p b^2$ is impossible

or p is not a prime factor of b. since 
$a^2 = mp b^2$, we have $p | a^2$ so $p | a$ ($p|xy$ implies $p|x$ or $p|y$ when $p$ is prime, by  euclide’s theorem. We just set $x = y = a$)

then $p^2 | a^2$ 
then $p^2 | m p b^2$, that is $p | mb^2$ which contradicts with our hypothesis

Comment: Thank you,i think the logic is very similar to my base step...I just instantly jumped to using induction to prove it...how does one tell whether induction is appropriate or not at the outset?

Comment: Generally, induction is appropriate when it seems easier to prove the property knowing that it is true for a smaller m. The way of thinking you can adopt is : « if needed, I can assume the property is true for any smaller value. ». Then, if you actually use that hypothesis, you are using induction, if you don’t, then you didn’t need it